# Stars are now evil?

Tags: discussion, chat, wording, chat-stars

As a room owner of a chat.SE room, I recently noticed a button that I can use:

[image]

Great! I don't know when I would ever need to use it, but that's beside the point. When I click the button, this dialog comes up.

[image]

Since when are stars evil? I can kind of see how this would be correct (the stars are leaning against the post), but the wording is a little weird. Could we change it to something like:

> Remove stars *for* this post?

Or even

> Clear all stars *on* this post?

Please? It's one of those little things that really bug me!

Comment: So I guess it should be changed to "Star as spam/offensive"?

Comment: On the plus side, using "on" will remove 5 characters from the js file that everyone has to download all the time. Heck, why not make it "Remove these stars?".

Comment: @TravisJ I like where you're going with this... but can we do better? "*Remove stars?*"... *"del strz"*... Maybe just "`:( ?`"

Comment: I suppose the [definition of _against_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/against) in this case is " In contact with so as to rest or press on" or perhaps even "Directly opposite to; facing". So, it's not incorrect.

Comment: @AlE Not incorrect, but misleading to those users of Stack Exchange that aren't lexicographers.

Comment: Bug? Really? Because of phrasing?

Comment: @Oded I wasn't sure - if one squints at it, you can see a little centipede running around on the dialog.

Comment: I was not aware that everyone didn't know stars are evil. Unfortunately, this statement does not come with nearly as much photographic evidence as the assertion that unicorns are evil.

Comment: @Oded why not? Spelling mistake is kind of a bug, isn't it? Anyhow in this case it's more of a feature request, asking to change existing wording to something else which makes more sense. :)

Comment: I'd support the Bug tag on this one.  Since the Discussion seems tongue in cheek, we don't appear to be arguing about whether the semantics are incorrent.  SO has a double-digit Alexa ranking.  Pointing out a nick in what should be an exemplary, highly literate user experience is not a Feature Request, either.

Comment: What exactly do you think that star button means, anyway?  I don't know about you, but where *I'm* from, if you throw a ninja star at something, you are pretty darn likely to be *against* it.